# How to use two UIPickerViews in one view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview

I have two `UIPickerController`s in one view controller. I can get one to work, but when I add a second, my app crashes. Here is the code I use for one picker view:

```
import UIKit

class RegisterJobPosition: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var positionLabel: UILabel!

    var position = ["Lifeguard", "Instructor", "Supervisor"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(PickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return position.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
    {
        return position[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {        
        positionLabel.text = position[row]
    }
}
```

Now, how can I get a second picker to work? Say my second picker view is called `location` (the other one is called `position`). I tried duplicating the code within the picker view methods for `location` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need a way to distinguish between the two of them if your view controller is the sole delegate for handling user interaction.   Can you post the code you're using to differentiate them?

Comment: I just duplicate the code. For example, in the numberOfRowsInComponent method, I just put: return location.count

Comment: That part makes sense.  But how are you programmatically figuring out which picker instance you're returning a count for?  If you've got two picker instances sending messages to your single view controller (delegate), you need a way to identify the pickers so you can do appropriate branch logic and return the right count for the right picker.

Comment: Ah....I wouldn't be able to set a "dummy" variable to tell the app which picker I want because I want both to be available at the same time.....how else could I do it?

Comment: I wrote an article on distinguishing between multiple UIActionSheets by using their tag property: http://bit.ly/DistinguishUIActionSheetsSwift -- While not exactly the same, the scenarios are similar.

Comment: Thanks for the link...what you wrote makes sense so I'll pull out bits and pieces when I get a chance :)

Comment: My pleasure.  If it still isn't working, try updating the question with more specifics on the error, and new code snippets with your branching logic.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on the information I have in the question, I'd say that you need to set up the data source & delegate methods to handle the ability to distinguish between which picker instance is calling them.

[Using the tag property](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/11/16/distinguishing-between-multiple-uiactionsheets-with-swift/) on the picker view is one strategy.

There should be some if/else or switch statements in the methods that have varying logic depending on whether it's the location or the position picker that's being referenced.

Comment: Regarding the if/else statements, how would I even get a variable to become a value that tells the location or position picker to be used?

Comment: So, if you set the tag on the pickers in the storyboard, you can test it in the callback method.  Do you see that the first parameter in the method is a pickerView?  You can check pickerView.tag and perform the right logic based on the tag's correlation to your UI and your data array.

Answer (score 80):

Here is my solution:

- in the storyboard, add two `UIPickerView` instances to your view
- set the first picker's tag as `1` and set `2` for the second picker under the "Attributes Inspector"
- <kbd>control</kbd> + drag from each picker to the top yellow view controller icon and choose `dataSource`. Repeat the same choosing `delegate`
- add `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` to your view controller:

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
  ```
- in your view controller class, create empty arrays for the pickers:

  ```
  var picker1Options = []
  var picker2Options = []
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad()`, populate the arrays with your content:

  ```
  picker1Options = ["Option 1","Option 2","Option 3","Option 4","Option 5"]
  picker2Options = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5"]
  ```
- implement the delegate and data source methods:

  ```
  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
      if pickerView.tag == 1 {
          return picker1Options.count
      } else {
          return picker2Options.count
      }
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
      if pickerView.tag == 1 {
          return "\(picker1Options[row])"
      } else {
          return "\(picker2Options[row])"
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for tag suggestion,which really help me alot using multiple picker.I got solved now.

Comment: This blows my mind off  how difficult it is to fill multiple PickerViews in the same ViewController. On Android its super simple.

Comment: Lazar K that's a very hateful comment. It is not simpler nor more complex. It's just a different strategy. On Android you would (or should) use different adapters for different Spinners. Actually you can use different Data Sources and Delegates on iOS too. I would actually suggest this in an answer

Comment: Rather than using tags, which are error prone, you can just have two picker view properties (eg `@IBOutlet var locationPickerView` and `positionPickerView`) in the class and check if `pickerView` in the delegate/data source methods is equal to either property.

Comment: Similar to [Diavel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320078/1032372) answer.

Answer (score 12):

I found this to work.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var textbox1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textbox2: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dropdown1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropdown2: UIPickerView!

    var age = ["10-20", "20-30", "30-40"]
    var Gender = ["Male", "Female"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var countrows : Int = age.count
        if pickerView == dropdown2 {
            countrows = self.Gender.count
        }

        return countrows
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == dropdown1 {
            let titleRow = age[row]
             return titleRow
        } else if pickerView == dropdown2 {
            let titleRow = Gender[row]
            return titleRow
        }

        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == dropdown1 {
            self.textbox1.text = self.age[row]
        } else if pickerView == dropdown2 {            
            self.textbox2.text = self.Gender[row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution I feel is much better than using the tags

Answer (score 2):

My background is in Android but my answer is very OOP. I would suggest creating different classes to implement the DataSource and Delegate like this:

```
class PositionDataSourceDelegate : NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
   var position = ["Lifeguard", "Instructor", "Supervisor"]
   var selectedPosition : String?

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
      return position.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
       return position[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       selectedPosition = position[row]
    }
}
```

and then another one for the Location:

```
class LocationDataSourceDelegate : NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
   var location = ["Up", "Down", "Everywhere"]
   var selectedLocation : String?

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return location.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
         return location[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedLocation = location[row]
   }
}
```

then in your RegisterJobPosition you need to create an instance of each:

```
let positionDSD = PositionDataSourceDelegate()
let locationDSD = LocationDataSourceDelegate()
```

and assign them to the pickers like this:

```
positionPicker.dataSource = positionDSD
positionPicker.delegate = positionDSD
locationPicker.dataSource = locationDSD
locationPicker.delegate = locationDSD
```

and you can access the selected position and location using:

```
positionDSD.selectedPosition 
locationDSD.selectedLocation
```

Hope this helps you and others and I'm also hoping for some constructive comments of why this is not "swifty"

Comment: It's a good OO solution, but it doesn't actually work in practice—I'm an iOS newcomer, but in trying to solve exactly this problem all day, and it appears to me that a UIPickerViewDelegate/DataSource must also be a UIViewController. A plain NSObject doesn't work.

Comment: `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` can be applied to any `NSObject`. Just tested it out and it seems to work fine. See no reason why these particular protocols wouldn't work for non-UIViewControllers, as that goes against how the SDK is designed. Breaking out data sources into their own classes is a great idea that not enough iOS developers are doing.

Comment: You can take Matei's suggestion one step further if you are using Storyboards.Drag an "Object" onto your VC and give it type PositionDataSourceDelegate.Create an outlet in your VC code connected to this object (Open assistant window next to storyboard and CTRL drag from Storyboard to VC code. You can call the outlet positionDSD ). Connect Picker's datasource and delegate methods to the object. Finally delete the let positionDSD =.. and  positionPicker.dataSource =... positionPicker.delegate =

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest issue and different to Java is that Java easily allow for attributes to be passed through the constructor. e.g. you could declare class LocationDataSourceDelegate as generic and call it genericDataSourceDelegate and make the constructor accept and Array public genericDataSourceDelegate (String data[]) and be able to make one class where could just simply create objects of. You just instantiate it and pass location the constructor like genericDataSourceDelegate (location)

The problem with your model you will have to create as many delegate classes in one program which is a strain to your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You should **NEVER** use tags!!!!!

The best way for me was:

1. Create an enum, for example `MyPickerViewType`

```
    enum MyPickerViewType {
        case first
        case second
    }
```

2. Create `CustomPickerView` class that conforms to `UIPickerView` and add `type` parameter

```
    class CustomPickerView: UIPickerView {
        let type: MyPickerViewType
    
        init(type: MyPickerViewType) {
            self.type = type
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }
    
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) is not supported")
        }
    }
```

3. Initialise custom pickerViews in UIViewController

```
    private lazy var firstPickerView: TimeLogCardPickerView = {
        let pickerView = TimeLogCardPickerView(type: .first)
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        return pickerView
    }()
    
    private lazy var secondPickerView: TimeLogCardPickerView = {
        let pickerView = TimeLogCardPickerView(type: .second)
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        return pickerView
    }()
```

4. Usage

```
    extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
    
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            let customPickerView = pickerView as? CustomPickerView

            switch customPickerView?.type {
            case .first:
                return 2
            case .second:
                return 5
            }
        }
    
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            let customPickerView = pickerView as? CustomPickerView

            switch customPickerView?.type {
            case .first:
                return firstTitleArray[row]
            case .second:
                return secondTitleArray[row]
            }
        }
    }
```