# Having multiple Picker Views

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uipickerview

I am trying to have multiple picker views in one single view in swift.
So far I have created 2 different textfields and I want both of them to have different picker views if I click on them. so let us say if click on textfield #1 it opens the array #1 and textfields #2 the second.

I have already looked up these questions but they do not really answer my question or solve my problem:

[Multiple Picker Views on a single view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997820/multiple-picker-views-on-a-single-view)

[Creating Multiple Dynamic Picker Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415345/creating-multiple-dynamic-picker-views)

so my View Controller looks like this:

[how my viewController should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMgZI.png)

and this is my piece of code:

```
let pickOption = ["kg","lb"] //first array for first textfield
let ageOption = ["0-5", "6-10", "11-15"] //array for 2nd textfield
let pickerView = UIPickerView()

//picker View functions
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickOption.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickOption[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    weightTextField.text = pickOption[row]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    weightTextField.inputView = pickerView
    weightTextField.text = pickOption[0]
}
```

so as mentioned before, the first textfield opens up the array 'pickOption' and the second array opens up 'ageOption'

EDIT: 'weightTextField' ist the first textfield which opens up the first array(pickOption)

Comment: if pickerView == xxx {};else if pickerView == yyy {}; else {}

Comment: @ElTomato hey thank you for your answer! But i do not get what you mean with that. Can you explain this for me? I am new to ios and swift programming!

Comment: I gave sample for, one picker view for multiple textfields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it for multiple `UITextField` from single `PickerView`, with the help of `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
let pickOption = ["kg","lb"] //first array for first textfield
let ageOption = ["0-5", "6-10", "11-15"] //array for 2nd textfield
let pickerView = UIPickerView()

var currentTxtFldTag : Int = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    weightTextField.tag = 10
    ageTextField.tag = 20

    weightTextField.delegate = self
    ageTextField.delegate = self

    weightTextField.inputView = pickerView
    weightTextField.text = pickOption[0]
    ageTextField.inputView = pickerView
    ageTextField.text = ageOption[0]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if currentTxtFldTag == 10
    {
        return pickOption.count
    }
    else
    {
        return ageOption.count
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if currentTxtFldTag == 10
    {
        return pickOption[row]
    }
    else
    {
        return ageOption[row]
    }

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if currentTxtFldTag == 10
    {
        weightTextField.text = pickOption[row]
    }
    else
    {
        ageTextField.text = ageOption[row]
    }


}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag == 10  // WEIGHT OPTION
    {
        currentTxtFldTag = 10
    }
    else  // AGE OPTION
    {
        currentTxtFldTag = 20
    }

    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    return true
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes !! thats what im looking for! thank you so much! :)

Comment: You don’t need tags for this. Just keep a reference to the current UITextField.

Comment: var currentTxtFldTag  = UITextField ?? Like this ??

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have two pickerView controls: picker0 and picker1.

```
class HomeViewController: BasicViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    let numberArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180]
    var areaArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var picker0: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        // area //
        for i in 0..<11 {
            let str = "Area "
            let localStr = NSLocalizedString(str + String(i), comment: "")
            areaArray.append(localStr)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Campaign duration & area
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == picker0 {
            return numberArray.count
        } else {
            return areaArray.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == picker0 {
            return String(numberArray[row]) + " pieces"
        } else {
            return areaArray[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == seventhPicker {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah i see what you are doing there! i am trying to fix the problem! thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    weightTextField.inputView = pickerView

} 

    let pickOption = ["kg","lb"] //first array for first textfield
    let ageOption = ["0-5", "6-10", "11-15"] //array for 2nd textfield
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    //picker View functions
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if weightTextField1.tag == 1 {
            return pickOption.count
        } else if weightTextField2.tag == itemPicker {
            return ageOption.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
          if weightTextField1.tag == 1 {
            return pickOption[row]
        } else if weightTextField2.tag == 1 {
            return ageOption[row]
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

          if weightTextField1.tag == 1 {
                weightTextField1.text = pickOption[row]
        } else if weightTextField2.tag == 1 {
        weightTextField2.text = ageOption[row]
        }

    }


    ////set delegate 

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method

      if textField == weightTextField1
    {
            weightTextField1.atg = 1;
            weightTextField2.atg = 0;
        }
    else  if textField == weightTextField2
    {
       weightTextField1.atg = 0;
      weightTextField2.atg = 1;
    }
        picker.reloadAllComponents()
       }
    }
```

Comment: @VDuc try this with textfield delegates