# How to use multiple UIPickerViews in one view controller

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am trying to set up 2 UIPickerViews in 1 view controller. I have not been able to find resources that solve my problem.

I have tried following the answer from Diavel Rider on [How to use 2 UIPickerView's in one View Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642164/how-to-use-2-uipickerviews-in-one-view-controller). I got some errors from that. I have also tried adding tags but was not able to successfully do that. I am using Swift 4.

Here is the code of my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ foodTypeUIPickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var countrows : Int = nutritionPickerData.count
        if pickerView == foodTypeUIPickerView { **[Error Here: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'UIPickerView'"]**
            countrows = self.foodTypePickerData.count
        }
        return countrows
    }

    func pickerView(_ foodTypeUIPickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == nutritionUIPickerView { **[Error Here: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'UIPickerView'"]**
            let titleRow = nutritionPickerData[row]
            return titleRow
        } else if pickerView == foodTypeUIPickerView { **[Error Here: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'UIPickerView'"]**
            let titleRow = foodTypePickerData[row]
            return titleRow
        }

        return ""

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nutritionUIPickerView: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var foodTypeUIPickerView: UIPickerView!

    var nutritionPickerData = ["Protein", "Fiber", "Iron", "Fat", "Sodium", "Calcium/Vitamin D", "Energy", "Carbohydrates", "Cholestorol"]
    var foodTypePickerData = ["Fruits", "Vegetables", "Legumes and Beans", "Grain", "Meat", "Dairy"]

    @IBAction func submitUIButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.nutritionUIPickerView.delegate = self
        self.nutritionUIPickerView.dataSource = self

        self.foodTypeUIPickerView.delegate = self
        self.foodTypeUIPickerView.dataSource = self

    }


}
```

I need to use 2 picker views in 1 view controller. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a non-existent variable named `pickerView`. You should update the parameter name to `pickerView` to avoid issues.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == foodTypeUIPickerView {
        return self.foodTypePickerData.count
    } else {
        return self. nutritionPickerData.count
    }
}
```

Make a similar change to the other delegate/data source methods.

Comment: How do I get the output for this now? I am trying to get the output for each of the pickerviews.

Comment: If you have a new question then please post a new question with all relevant code and details about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your data sources and delegates and not put them inside your view controller. Set those as the delegate and datasource.  Code written in swift 4.2 xcode 10.1

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var foodPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nutritionPicker: UIPickerView!

    var foodData = FoodData()
    var nutritionData = NutritionData()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        foodPicker.delegate = foodData
        foodPicker.dataSource = foodData

        nutritionPicker.delegate = nutritionData
        nutritionPicker.dataSource = nutritionData
    }

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let food = foodPicker.delegate?.pickerView!(foodPicker, titleForRow: foodPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0), forComponent: 0)

        let nutrition = nutritionPicker.delegate?.pickerView!(nutritionPicker, titleForRow: nutritionPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0), forComponent: 0)

        print("You picked: \(food) and \(nutrition)")
    }    
}

class FoodData: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var foodTypePickerData = ["Fruits", "Vegetables", "Legumes and Beans", "Grain", "Meat", "Dairy"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return foodTypePickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return foodTypePickerData[row]
    }
}

class NutritionData: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var nutritionPickerData = ["Protein", "Fiber", "Iron", "Fat", "Sodium", "Calcium/Vitamin D", "Energy", "Carbohydrates", "Cholestorol"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return nutritionPickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return nutritionPickerData[row]
    }
}
```