# incorrect array showing in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have two UIPickerviews that appear on one ViewController.  I have tried to follow the following [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642164/how-to-use-two-uipickerviews-in-one-view-controller).

I have followed the suggestion in that I have tagged each of the UITextFields (I have 4 in total). See the the image.

[image: UIView of Storyboard]

Below is the code for the UIPickerViews.

```
extension DriverViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return tracks.count
        } else {
            return drivers.count
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return "\(tracks[row])"
        } else {
            return "\(drivers[row])"
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the tracks array appear on all of the UITextfields.

Below is the code for each of the Arrays and the title of the UIPickerView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tracks = ["Melbourne", "Manama", "Shanghai", "Baku",
              "Barcelona", "Monaco", "Montreal","Le Castellet","Spielberg",
              "Silverstone","Hockenheim","Budapest","Francorchamps","Monza","Singapore","Sochi","Suzuka","Austin","Interlagos","Abu Dhabi"]
    drivers = ["Lewis Hamilton","Antonio Giovinazzi","Kimi Raikkonen","Charles Leclerc","Sebastian Vettel","Romain Grosjean","Kevin Magnussen","Lando Norris",
               "Carlos Sainz","Valtteri Bottas","Sergio Perez","Lance Stroll","Pierre Gasly","Max Verstappen","Nico Hulkenberg","Daniel Ricciardo","Alexander Albon","Daniil Kvyat","Robert Kubica","George Russell"]
    createTrackPicker()
    createDriverPicker()
    createToolBar()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func createTrackPicker() {
    let trackPicker = UIPickerView()
    trackPicker.delegate = self
    TrackTextField.inputView = trackPicker
}

func createDriverPicker() {
    let driverPicker = UIPickerView()
    driverPicker.delegate = self
    firstTextField.inputView = driverPicker
    secondTextField.inputView = driverPicker
    thirdTextField.inputView = driverPicker
}

func createToolBar() {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    TrackTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    firstTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    secondTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    thirdTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the tag.

```
func createDriverPicker() {
    let driverPicker = UIPickerView()
    driverPicker.tag = 1 // <—-
```